# What is the printing resolution of a XAML file?

Tags: xaml, printing, expression-blend

I'm a designer and I like having a little control over the dimensions...
I am styling a XAML file that is meant to be printed.
Since dimensions are in pixels, I'd like to know which resolution I should base myself to calculate lengths (in cm)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[According to Charles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh148152.aspx), Silverlight is fixed at 96 DPI:

> As you know, a Silverlight program normally sizes graphical objects
>   and controls entirely in units of pixels. However, when the printer is
>   involved, coordinates and sizes are in device-independent units of
>   1/96th inch. Regardless of the actual resolution of the printer, from
>   a Silverlight program the printer always appears to be a 96 DPI
>   device.
>
> ...
>
> PrintPageEventArgs has two handy get-only properties that also report
>   sizes in units of 1/96th inch: PrintableArea of type Size provides the
>   dimensions of the area of the printable area of the page, and
>   PageMargins of type Thickness is the width of the left, top, right and
>   bottom of the unprintable edges. Add these two together (in the right
>   way) and you get the full size of the paper.

I did some quick searching, but couldn't turn up this info in the documentation.  Leave it to Charles to know this sort of information.